# setting system python path in OSX

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

I am using `OSX`. Suppose I have installed `pyenv` and that, when installing a package, I am asked to provide `PYTHON2_LIBRARY` variable that I set to `/home/username/.pyenv/shims/python`. Now, I think that there are some lib path conflicts. How can I set back to the system `python` and in which path can I find it ?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions for how to completely uninstall pyenv are here: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

I would strongly suggest checking out virtualenvwrapper and virtualenv if you're using py2.x

Py3 has venv built into it.